# Getting Grails to read my submitted JSON PUT AJAX request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, grails, grails-orm

I have my form here, nothing out of the ordinary as a Grails app is concerned.

```
<g:form url="[resource:myClass, action:'update']" method="PUT" >
    <fieldset class="form">
        <g:render template="form"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <g:actionSubmit action="update" value="update" />
    </fieldset>
</g:form>
```

If I do a regular submit, everything works fine.  But if I try to use my restfulcontroller, I get a successful save message, but it never saves anything.

```
import grails.rest.RestfulController
import grails.transaction.Transactional

class MyClassRestController extends RestfulController<MyClass> {
    static allowedMethods = [update: "PUT"]
    @SuppressWarnings("GroovyUnusedDeclaration")
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']  

    @Transactional
    def update(MyClass myClassInstance) {
        myClassInstance.save flush:true, failOnError: true
        respond new Expando(success: true, message: 'updated', myClass: myClassInstance)
    }
}
```

This seems straightforward, and here is how I am submitting it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var frm = $('form');
        frm.on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                url: putUrl,
                data: JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray()),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.info(data);
                },
                failure: function (errMsg) {
                    console.info(errMsg)
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Everything appears to PUT correct in the console, I get my success message back and the MyClassInstance, but it is the unedited MyClass - it is as if it is looking it up via GORM and ignoring what my PUT is sending.  What am I forgetting?  Do I have to set anything for the PUT to 'take hold' and the myClassInstance?

Here is my request: [image]

Ignore the created date part, it is overwritten.  And here is the response:

```
{   
    "metaPropertyValues": [     
        {
            "class":"groovy.lang.MetaExpandoProperty",
            "modifiers":1,
            "name":"success",
            "type":"java.lang.Object"
        },  
        {
            "class":"groovy.lang.MetaExpandoProperty",
            "modifiers":1,
            "name":"message",
            "type":"java.lang.Object"
        },
        {
            "class":"groovy.lang.MetaExpandoProperty",
            "modifiers":1,
            "name":"auctionUser",
            "type":"java.lang.Object"
        }
    ],
    "properties":{
        "success":true,
        "message":"AuctionUser updated",
        "auctionUser":{
            "class":"Auction.AuctionUser",
            "id":2,
            "addressCity":"Minneapolis",
            "addressState":"MN",
            "addressStreet":"1234 ABC Street",
            "addressZip":"55408",
            "created":"2015-03-31T05:00:00Z",
            "firstName":"Trat",
            "lastName":"Tauer",
            "username":"trat@naspinski.net"
        }
    }
}
```

You can ignore most of it, but notice that the addressStreet and firstName are returned as the previous values and not as the JSON that was passed via the PUT.  What is wrong here?

Comment: Did you look at the firebug network tab and see what is it submitting ? upload screenshot somewhere

Comment: added the request/response to take a look at

Comment: Two things to notice here: 1. The payload is a JSON Array and we are expecting it to bind it to the command object `MyClass`. This will not work. The payload has to be a JSON object instead. 2. For HTTP PUT requests, the JSON Object payload has to have an `id` element in the body based on which the `get` method will be called on the domain class which is used as command object in data binding. I am not sure whether `id` is present in the payload.

Comment: id is not present, it is actually sent in the url (controller/action/id) - is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the form with HTTP method="PUT", which is not valid and will end up [using the default method GET](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fs-method)

What Grails does is to use a POST parameter to tunnel the HTTP method

```
<g:form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" >
    <g:hiddenField name="_method" value="PUT" />
```

Try this

```
<g:form url="[resource:myClass, action:'update']" method="POST" >
    <g:hiddenField name="_method" value="PUT" />
    <fieldset class="form">
        <g:render template="form"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <g:actionSubmit action="update" value="update" />
    </fieldset>
</g:form>
```